# Get grunt-stylint to listen to all stylus files

Tags: npm, gruntjs, stylus, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to get my Gruntfile.js to lint all my stylus files using grunt-stylint, but I am having trouble getting it to listen to all my stylus files, particularly those in subdirectories.

Here is my styles structure:

```
- assets
 - styles
   bunch-of-files.styl
   - components
      even-more-files.styl
```

I've got it watching all stylus files with this:

```
watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: true,
  },
  pug: {
    files: '**/*.pug',
    tasks: ['puglint'],
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },
  },
  stylus: {
    files: '**/*.styl',
    tasks: ['stylint','stylus'],
  },
  scripts :{
    files: 'assets/js/*.js',
    tasks: ['concat'],
    options: {
      interrupt: false,
    },
  },
  server: {
    files: ['.rebooted'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  } 
},
```

But, the stylint task only looks at the `bunch-of-files` with this, and not the `components/` folder:

```
stylint: {
  options: {
    config: '.stylintrc'
  },
  src: ['**/*.styl']
},
```

Others I've tried with the same results:

```
stylint: {
  options: {
    config: '.stylintrc'
  },
  src: ['assets/styles/**/*.styl']
},

stylint: {
  options: {
    config: '.stylintrc'
  },
  src: ['**/**/*.styl']
},
```

The only thing that worked was this, but now it only looks in that `components/` directory:

```
stylint: {
  options: {
    config: '.stylintrc'
  },
  src: ['assets/styles/*/*.styl']
},
```

And when I pair that with one of the earlier ones, it only reads the first file. For example this only will read those `bunch-of-files`.

```
stylint: {
  options: {
    config: '.stylintrc'
  },
  src: ['**/*.styl','assets/styles/*/*.styl']
},
```

Ideas?

**

editing w full gruntfile + package.json

Gruntfile:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    stylus: {
      build: {
        options: {
          compress: false,
        },
        files: {
          'public/css/main.css': 'assets/styles/main.styl',
        }
      }
    },

    concat: {
      options: {
        stripBanners: true,
      },
      basic: {
        src: ['assets/js/*.js'],
        dest: 'public/js/main.js',
      },
    },

    jshint: {
      all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app.js', 'assets/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        force: true,
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true,
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        },
      },
    },

    stylint: {
      options: {
        config: '.stylintrc'
      },
      src: ['**/*.styl']
    },

    puglint: {
      src: '**/*.pug',
      options: {
        requireClassLiteralsBeforeAttributes: true,
        requireIdLiteralsBeforeAttributes: true,
        requireLowerCaseAttributes: true,
        requireLowerCaseTags: true,
        validateIndentation: 2,
        disallowDuplicateAttributes: true,
        validateAttributeQuoteMarks: "\""
      }
    },

    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true,
      },
      pug: {
        files: '**/*.pug',
        tasks: ['puglint'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
      },
      stylus: {
        files: '**/*.styl',
        tasks: ['stylint','stylus'],
      },
      scripts :{
        files: 'assets/js/*.js',
        tasks: ['concat'],
        options: {
          interrupt: false,
        },
      },
      server: {
        files: ['.rebooted'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      } 
    },

    nodemon: {
      dev: {
        script: 'app.js',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
          env: {
            PORT: '3000'
          },
          // omit this property if you aren't serving HTML files and 
          // don't want to open a browser tab on start
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // refreshes browser when server reboots
            nodemon.on('restart', function () {
              // Delay before server listens on port
              setTimeout(function() {
                require('fs').writeFileSync('.rebooted', 'rebooted');
              }, 1000);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    concurrent: {
      target: [['jshint', 'stylint', 'stylus', 'puglint', 'concat', 'watch'],'nodemon' ],
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
      }
    }

  });

  // Load plugins.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-stylint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-puglint');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent']);

  };
```

Package.json

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "font-awesome-stylus": "^4.5.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-stylus": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-puglint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-stylint": "^0.1.2",
    "mustache-express": "^1.2.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "pug-lint-config-clock": "^1.1.1",
    "reload": "^0.7.0",
    "stylint": "^1.3.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can u post your full gruntfile and your packgae.json ? thank you

Comment: @Raduken added my package.json and full Gruntfile

Comment: i gonna do a local test here.